# Changing css class in knockout.js on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

The knockout.js documentation shows the css binding like this:

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0 }">   
    Profit Information
</div>
```

I need to adapt it to change the css class on mouseclick. How can I do this?

Based on answers below, I am using some code like this:

```
// CSS class to be applied
<style>
    .bigclass
    {
        width: 200px;
    }

</style>

// Select list inside a jquery .tmpl
<script id='criteriaRowTemplate' type='text/html'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-bind='click: makeBig, css: {bigclass : SelectHasFocus() > 0}' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</script> 

// Knockout.js Viewmodel
var CriteriaLine = function() {
    this.SearchCriterion = ko.observable();
    this.SelectHasFocus = ko.observable(0);

    // this method is called
    makeBig = function(element) { 
        this.SelectHasFocus(1);            
    };        
};
```

However, this is not expanding the width of the select list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you have `ko.applyBindings(CriteriaLine())` somewhere after your document loads, right?  Your code works as shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6896T/4/).

Answer (score 17):

Have your click function change an observable variable.  For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/6896T/57/):

```
<div data-bind="css: { myclass: newClass() == true }">
   Profit Information
</div>

<button data-bind="click: changeClass">Change Class</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = {
        newClass: ko.observable(false),
        changeClass: function() {
            viewModel.newClass(true);
        }
    }; 
</script>
```

Note: You can combine `click` and `css` on the same element.  For example:

```
<div databind="click: changeClass, css: { myclass: newClass() == true }"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Pakman. I tried code similar to yours but it doesn't work. I have added the code in my original question. Can you see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a [click binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) which changes an observable in the callback. You would bind the class appropriately using something like the [attr binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I would be highly obliged if you can provide sample code, particularly if it involves a select list. I need to use the css class to increase the width of the entire select list.

Comment: I have added some sample code but it doesn't work. Would you know what's going wrong?

Comment: This may just be an artifact of preparing the code for stack overflow, but makeBig is private and wouldn't be accessible by the bindings.

change

makeBig = function... to this.makeBig = function...

Comment: Thanks daedalus28 but makeBig method is being called. I had an alert inside it and it did popup the desired text. I am not sure though, if SelectHasFocus() > 0 is being evaluated or not as it is outside the viewmodel and in a template.

Comment: Why not make SelectHasFocus a bool instead? Then you can just use SelectHasFocus instead of  currentProfit() < 0. A boolean value seem to make more sense anyway

Comment: Callbacks provided to knockout js bindings ought to not know about the structure of the view. This breaks the separation of concerns. Models and controllers ought to be view agnostic and no nothing about the views structure in good mvc design.

Comment: @eniac - Given your downvote, perhaps I should have clarified. I was not suggesting you'd manually change the class in the callback directly, but rather change an observable property on the view model to which the class is bound to (such as with an attr binding).

Comment: @eniac - I just updated my answer in case you'd like to retract your downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel the problem is with script tag.

Please find the solution in following link: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmU6g/3/

Comment: Maybe you can post the solution here in addition to the jsfiddle for ease of reference?