# Disable Button in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor, knockout.js

I had a table which will bind the record from the database every page load function using KnockoutJs.

```
<table class="tbl" data-bind="visible: Page().length > 0">

    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Page">

        <tr>


            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: TimeType" id="TimeType" ></span> 
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: right;">
                <button class="btn1" data-bind="click: delete" id="Check-In">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Check-In</button>
                <button class="btn1" data-bind="click: clickCheckout"  id="Check-Out" >Check-Out</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

In above table i had one lable and two buttons, `TimeType` as lable and `Check-In` and `Check-Out` as button. I need to disable the button which was clicked and other need to be enable. If `check-in` is clicked then the lable will has value as `CheckIn` otherwise empty. In page load if lable has checkin value in that it also need to work as button click function i.e. I need to disable the button Check-In and enable the other one.

But that functionality is working in button click event,

```
$("#Check-In").live("click", function () {

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).css('background', "green");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-Out').css("background", "");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-Out').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#TimeType').text('Checkin');
        $('#Check-Out').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $("#Check-Out").live("click", function () {
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $(this).css('background', "green");
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#TimeType').text('');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-In').removeAttr('disabled');
        $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-In').css("background", "");

    });
```

But in page load its not working

```
function fnLoad() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller", new { Id = new})',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: {},
            success: function (data) {
                self.List(data);
                 $.each(data, function () {

                    var time = this.TimeType

                    if (time == '') {

                             $(this).parent().parent().find("#Check-Out").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                             $(this).parent().parent().find("#Check-Out").css('background', "green");
                             $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-In').removeAttr('disabled');
                             $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-In').css("background", "");

                    }

                        if (time == 'Checkin') {

                                $(this).parent().parent().find("#Check-In").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                $(this).parent().parent().find("#Check-In").css('background', "green");
                                $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-Out').css("background", "");
                                $(this).parent().parent().find('#Check-Out').removeAttr('disabled');


                          }


                    });

            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are going off the track , you should use knokcout for event binding as you have knockout so why still using Jquery events .

After that you can make a boolean observable for each button and add that observable with disable binding . For disable binding you can have a look at this [Disable/Enable Binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) . Think this will help you

Comment: Thanks for that it's helpful for me to enable and disable but is there anything to change the color of the button as doing in a button click

Comment: Yes why not , you can have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234920/changing-css-class-in-knockout-js-on-mouse-click

Comment: Yeah, thanks its work fine, I had been using `Style` instead of `CSS`. So by using  `CSS` its works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="tbl" data-bind="visible: Page().length > 0">

<tbody data-bind="foreach: Page">

    <tr>


        <td>
            <span data-bind="text: TimeType" id="TimeType" ></span> 
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: right;">
            <button class="btn1" data-bind="click: $root.delete, enable: !TimeType, css: { bigclass: TimeType != '' }" value="text: UserId" id="Check-In">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Check-In</button>
                <button class="btn1" data-bind="click: $root.clickCheckout, enable: TimeType, css: { bigclass: TimeType == ''} " value="text: UserId" id="Check-Out" >Check-Out</button>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

CSS

```
.bigclass
  {
      background-color:green;
  }
```

Here in above code if `Time Type` has any value then `Check out` will enable  and removed the class. `Time Type` will take value from database as I required and if the `Time Type` is empty then `Check in` button will enable and removed the class